# rspec spec gives "Failed to load /home/searching/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML /"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Failed to load /home/searching/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML

when i excute  this command rspec spec/

the above error will appear and not able to do the test case using spec

Comment: What is contained in ` /home/searching/.gemrc`?

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
supported runtimes
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc, require: false

gem 'spring',        group: :developmentgroup :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gemrc` is not `Gemfile`.

`.gemrc` are YAML files with the following YAML keys:

```
:sources: A YAML array of remote gem repositories to install gems from
:verbose: Verbosity of the gem command. false, true, and :really are the
          levels
:update_sources: Enable/disable automatic updating of repository metadata
:backtrace: Print backtrace when RubyGems encounters an error
:gempath: The paths in which to look for gems
:disable_default_gem_server: Force specification of gem server host on push
<gem_command>: A string containing arguments for the specified gem command
```

Example:

```
:verbose: false
install: --no-wrappers
update: --no-wrappers
:disable_default_gem_server: true
```

It is described in details here: http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/

Comment: rm -f home/seaerching/.gemrc It works for me.I got to know that no need of .gemrc file , if it is not found it will take default.

Comment: @-MikDiet Anyway thanks for your help, first i was confusion between gemfile and gemrc.